# CardLayout syntax // .add()

Tags: java, awt, cardlayout

From following code snippet which I taken from [CardLayoutDemo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/CardLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/CardLayoutDemo.java).

```
final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Card with JButtons";
final static String TEXTPANEL = "Card with JTextField";
```

-

```
//Create the panel that contains the "cards".
  cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
  cards.add(card1, BUTTONPANEL);
  cards.add(card2, TEXTPANEL);
```

I don't understand the usage of 2 strings above. I assume they are served as an indicator to particular card, but then why don't we use following code instead ?

```
//Create the panel that contains the "cards".
      cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
      cards.add(buttonPanel);
      cards.add(textPanel);
```

What I mean is these 2 Strings has no practical use at all which seems weird to me.

Sorry for my noobies and please forgive me if the question is vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `String` "name" is an identifier which allows you to instruct the `CardLayout` which view it should show, which is described below the code snippet you've posted in [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)...

```
//Method came from the ItemListener class implementation,
//contains functionality to process the combo box item selecting
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
    cl.show(cards, (String)evt.getItem());
}
```

Comment: yeah I totally missed that. thanks. I guess i need to get used to object-oriented concept a little more.